# Android Custom Theming in ActionBar/Tabs

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, theming

I have the theme Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

The tabs are now set to white background, light gray text--very unreadable.  I simply want to change the text to something much,  much darker.

I have searched the styles to see if I can override but all I can do is change the background, not the text.

Can I do this in the styles.xml or do I have to do this programmaticly?

Comment: It's interesting some have favorited this question, yet no answers.  How could something so basic be such a headache?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're referring to the `ActionBar`'s tab see if this changes the color:

```
<!-- The theme for the activity -->
<style name="TabSpecialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Modify the text color -->
<style name="TabStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
      <item name="android:textColor">#F70000</item>
</style>
```

Of course don't forget to set the theme for the activity to `@style/TabSpecialTheme` in the manifest.